# Чи є доречним словосполучення "практична реалізація"?

Tags: словосполучення

В колонці [новин](http://www.unn.com.ua/uk/news/1726466-predstavnik-yes-ochikuyemo-vid-ukrayini-praktichnu-realizatsiyu-zakonu-pro-audit) натрапила на таке речення: "В Європейському союзі очікують від України **практичну реалізацію** прийнятого в 2017 році закону про аудит." Згідно з СУМ-11,

> ПРАКТИ́ЧНИЙ, а, е
>
> 1. Стос. до практики (у 1—3 знач.); пов'язаний з життям і діяльністю людини.
>
> //  у сполуч. із сл. вага, значення, мета, цінність і т. ін.
>   Пов'язаний із життєвими, реальними потребами, можливостями; важливий
>   для життя.
>
> //  у сполуч. із сл. порада, допомога і т. ін. Потрібний, корисний
>   комусь для здійснення чогось на практиці.
>
> //  у сполуч. із сл. досвід, знання, навички і т. ін. Одержуваний,
>   набутий в результаті практики, діяльності.
>
> 2. Який безпосередньо здійснює яку-небудь справу, керує ким-, чим-небудь. Практичний центр керівництва повстанням.
> 3. у сполуч. із сл. заняття, навчання і т. ін. Який є практикою (у 4 знач.), пов'язаний із застосуванням, закріпленням якихось знань,
>      навичок на практиці.
> 4. Пов'язаний із застосуванням на практиці знань у галузі якої-небудь науки.
> 5. Який має життєвий досвід, добре розуміється на якихось справах (про людину): діловитий.
>
> //  у сполуч. із сл. розум, голова і т. ін. Власт. такій людині.
>
> 6. Вигідний, зручний для кого-, чого-небудь.

Не знайшла такого значення, що сполучалось би зі словом реалізація - втілення у життя. То чи правомірним є таке словосполучення?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ми можемо мати декілька реалізацій, але не всі можуть бути *практичними*. Від практичної реалізації на відміну від реалізації взагалі ми очікуємо додаткових характеристик, наприклад зручність у використанні, мале споживання палива, висока швидкодія, малий об'єм потрібної пам'яті тощо.

Реалізації практичні в одній ситуації можуть бути непрактичними в іншій. Наприклад, якщо в одній країні дешеве пальне, а в іншій дороге, то реалізація автомобіля практична в одній з країн може бути неприктичною в іншій.

Тут підходить пункт 6 з переліку в запитанні:

> Вигідний, зручний для кого-, чого-небудь.

Answer (score 5):

СУМ:

> РЕАЛІЗА́ЦІЯ, ї, жін. Дія за значенням реалізувати.
>   РЕАЛІЗУВА́ТИ, ую, уєш, недок. і док., перех.
>   1. Здійснювати, робити реальним, втілювати що-небудь у життя. Після Чумака лишився невеликий літературний доробок.. Нагла смерть не дала йому розгорнути сили, реалізувати всі можливості (Василь Еллан, II, 1958, 105); Валя кожну мою пораду ловила якось на льоту, вміла її реалізувати (Юрій Збанацький, Малин. дзвін, 1958, 362).

На мою думку термін *реалізація* сам по собі передбачає практику - здійснення, втілення в життя. Не може ж бути реалізація теоретичною, хоча можна обговорювати теоретичні аспекти повязані з майбутньою реалізацією. Тому в цьому словосполученні, я думаю, присутня тавтологія. Однак безліч [інтернет-ресурсів](https://www.google.com.ua/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_ukUA757UA757&ei=phfaWsTyCoKVsgHshZOwAw&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1l2j0i22i30k1l8.33966.39500.0.39647.22.21.1.0.0.0.106.2002.17j4.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.22.2005...0j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i203k1j0i22i30i19k1.0.FZ1URI-Bxtk), все-таки, вважають по-іншому, тому можливо я помиляюсь.